# Why does postsharp says I use a premium feature while afaik I don't?

Tags: c#, postsharp

I use postsharp and I'm using the `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` and according to [this](https://www.postsharp.net/get/community) it is available in the community edition. This is litteraly the only aspect I'm using.
I'm am however using a `postsharp.config` file and I don't know for sure it is a free feature.
The config file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration">
  <Multicast xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ExceptionAutoSerializer.Aspects;assembly:ExceptionAutoSerializer">
    <my:MethodBoundaryAspect  AttributeTargetTypes="My.Custom.Namespace.*" />
  </Multicast>
</Project>
```

When I try to compile a big project I get this error :

> License error. The project uses non-licensed premium features. It is not allowed to enhance types with a total of more than 1000 lines of code in the project by features not covered by the installed licenses, but 3949 lines of code were enhanced.    MyCustomProject

But it doesn't say what feature I use so it's kind of hard to debug. Is there any way I get to know what trigger the error ?

Comment: I don't know the full extent of the free features, but if you only just started experiencing this, can't you fairly easily back track to see which addition to your code caused it?

Comment: I used postsharp for like 4 weeks now in a PoC si it is not that simple to backtrack, but I'll do my best

Comment: Good to see you found the cause. To more easily find causes to issues like this (or many other code issues) I'd recommend you committing your code often as well as trying to build your code. Just a friendly suggestion if that's not what you're already doing. Small commits are good practice :)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on what's free and what's not is kinda hard to find imo. But I found [this](https://doc.postsharp.net/express-limitations) and this was how I solved it:

> Method decorators and interceptors :
>
> Both aspects OnMethodBoundaryAspect and MethodInterceptionAspect can
> be used for free, but semantic advising of async methods is a premium
> feature.
>
> To disable semantic advising, you have to set the
> SemanticallyAdvisedMethodKinds property to None in the aspect
> constructor.

Comment: To understand the consequences, read https://doc.postsharp.net/semantic-advising.